# Declaring a union pointer with a pointer inside

Tags: c++, malloc, sse, unions

I'm trying to learn SSE instructions and I aspire to multiply two matices. However, when I try to initialize one of them, the program crashes with an

> Access violation when typing in location

Here's the code that throws the error:

```
typedef union{
    __m128 vec;
    float* afloat;
}u_float;

int main(){

__declspec(align(16)) u_float *mat1;

mat1 = (u_float*)malloc(sizeof(u_float)*4);
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    mat1[i].afloat = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*4);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for(int j = 0; i < 4; j++)
            mat1[i].afloat[j] = 1; // Error.

return 0;}
```

1. Why is it throwing that error?
2. And which is the best way to resolve the problem?

Comment: In what way is this question related to SSE instructions?

Comment: @zx485 Later I'll use the  `_mm_mul_ps` and `_mm_hadd_ps` functions to multiply the matices. However the main problem here has nothing to do with SSE.

Comment: What the heck is the point of that union?  How does later code decide whether it's holding an `__m128` value or a pointer?  Did you mean to write `__m128 *vec`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `union`s. You have typo in your loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for(int j = 0; i < 4; j++) // <-- Here
            mat1[i].afloat[j] = 1;
```

Notice that the inner for loop loops while **i** is less than 4, not when **j** is less than 4, so this loops infinitely.

Comment: No worries! It's a heck of a lot better than hitting some esoteric language edge case. :-)